# Ubuntu Touch -Core App Telegram not activating the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, telegram

Over the last week when I try to type in Telegram the keyboard is not getting activated. If i click in the text field, theselect all and copy box appears, but not the keyboard. I havr to tapI in the text field five or so times to get the keyboard to appear.

Only seems to be happening in my bq e5.

Comment: Have you ever tried to do a reboot?

Comment: Every night I turn the phone off and turn it back on in the morning. Still the same Issie.